# Excel get_Range error for non contiguous ranges

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have the following piece of VSTO code which behaves strangely.

```
string s = "E6:N6,E8:N12,E14:N16,E18:N20,E23:N26,E28:N31,E33:N33,E35:N35,E37:N38,E40:N41,E43:N43,E45:N45,E47:N49,E52:N52,E55:N55,E58:N62,E64:N68,E70:N70,E72:N73,E76:N78,E80:N81,E83:N83,E86:N87";

Excel.Range r = worksheet.get_Range[s];
```

and when I check r.Address now it is:

```
"E6:N6,E8:N12,E14:N16,E18:N20,E23:N26,E28:N31,E33:N33,E35:N35,E37:N38,E40:N41,E43:N43,E45:N45,E47:N49,E52:N52,E55:N55,E58:N62,E64:N68,E70:N70,E72:N73,E76:N78,E80:N81"
```

Note that the last two areas are missing!

Is there any limitation to the number of areas that get_Range can handle?

Comment: FWIW The same happens with `ActiveSheet.Range(your_str).Address` within Excel itself (VBA), If I shorten some range address strings (`E1:N1` instead of `E14:N16`) more "fit" into the union so there is evidently a length limit somewhere ...

Comment: Check `r.Address(0, 0)`.

Comment: @Jeeped: Thanks `r.Address[0,0]` worked! and shows the missing areas. Could you pls explain why `r.Address` hide the later part of the address?

Comment: `Len(r.Address[0,0]) < Len(r.Address)`

Comment: @Jeeped: Pls put that as answer so that we can complete this q&a.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there does appear to be a limit in terms of the size of string that can be used with Excel range functions.

e.g. sheet.Range() will accept a range of up to 255 characters, after which will throw an error.

The same is true when evaluating the Address of a existing Range.

e.g. range.Address will return a string up to 255 characters in length, even if the range contains more values.

This is often an issue when selecting large numbers of non-contiguous cells.

The solution suggested by Jeeped, will only get you so far since it will return the cell address without the $, leaving more characters available for the address definition, however the character limit will eventually be reached.

The solution I came up with was to use the Areas property of the Range class and loop through these to construct the final address.

This address cannot be used with sheet.Range directly due to the character limit as above, so it must be unioned together to convert back to a usable range.

See the following methods on how to do this in c#:

```
    public static string GetRangeAddress( Range range )
    {
        string rangeAddress = string.Empty;

        int areaCount = 1;
        foreach (Range inputArea in range.Areas)
        {
            rangeAddress += inputArea.Address[0, 0];

            if (areaCount < range.Areas.Count)
                rangeAddress += ",";

            areaCount++;
        }

        return rangeAddress;
    }

    public static Range GetRangeFromAddress(Excel.Application app, Worksheet sheet, string address)
    {
        Range IR = null;

        string[] rangeAreas = address.Split(',');

        foreach (string area in rangeAreas)
        {
            if (IR != null)
                IR = app.Union(IR, sheet.Range[area]);
            else
                IR = sheet.Range[area];
        }

        return IR;
    }
```